# Add line to csv with commas

Tags: php, csv

I have this line on CSV file (products.csv)

```
"PRODUCT ID","PRICE","FILE","EMAIL TEMPLATE","EXPIRATION IN SECONDS","EMAIL TITLE"
"Ultimate Reminder","1.88","UltimateReminder.apk","01.html",10000,"Compra completada - UltimateReminder.apk"
```

I need a php code who add line to csv file respecting **"** like second line already are on CSV file.

I have this code, but don't add **"**:

```
<?php
$list = array
(
'Product 2,20.30,Product2.apk,01.html,1000,Payment Completed - Product2.apk'
);

$file = fopen('productos.csv','a');  // 'a' for append to file - created if doesn't exit

foreach ($list as $line)
  {
  fputcsv($file,explode('",',$line));
  }

fclose($file); 
?>
```

TIP: Number 1000, need be without **"**

**Question is: How I can add line to csv respecting *"*?**

Comment: Have you thought of using `implode()` after you splitted the `$line` via `explode()`? You could then use e.g. `","` as a delimiter.

Comment: I guess you are not exploding well. Try:
fputcsv($file, explode(',',$line));

Comment: Jose Carlos PHP, I tried you, but only add " to start & the end of _Product 2_ and _Payment Completed - Product2.apk_